# JPA: Find by Interface instead of Implementation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework, annotations

I want to use the find method with an interface, instead of using with the implementation.

That said here is my Code:

```
public Goods findGoods(Long goodsId) {
    return this.jpaApi.withTransaction(()->{
        Goods goods = null;
        try{
            EntityManager em = this.jpaApi.em();
            Query query = em.createQuery("select g from Goods g where id=:id", Goods.class);
            query.setParameter("id", goodsId);
            goods = (Goods) query.getSingleResult();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return goods;
    });
}
```

My Entity:

```
@Entity(name = "Goods")
@Table(name = "GOODS")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class GoodsImp implements Goods,  Serializable {
..
}
```

My Interface:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type", 
use = Id.NAME, defaultImpl = GoodsImp.class, visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({ @Type(value = ProductImp.class, name = "product"),
                @Type(value = ServiceImp.class, name = "service") })
@ImplementedBy(GoodsImp.class)
public interface Goods {
..
}
```

Error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate persister: interfaces.Goods
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3422)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3365)
>           at repository.JPAGoodsRepository.lambda$deleteGoods$2(JPAGoodsRepository.java:58)
>           at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.lambda$withTransaction$3(DefaultJPAApi.java:197)

My doubt is why i have this issue, if when I use a Query statement works fine with the interface.

This works:

```
 @Override
    public Collection<Goods> getAllGoods() {
        return this.jpaApi.withTransaction(() -> {
            Collection<Goods> goods = null;
            try {
                EntityManager em = this.jpaApi.em();
                Query query = em.createQuery("Select g from Goods g", Goods.class);
                goods = query.getResultList();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return goods;
        });

    }
```

Comment: The JPA API doesn't consider interfaces to be worthy of persistence handling. DataNucleus JPA does allow that JPQL, but don't know of any others that do, and you're into vendor extensions there anyway

Comment: So, I can only use the interface in JPQL but not in .find method?

Comment: As I said, JPA does not consider interfaces, so you cant use them if sticking to the spec and only 1 vendor I know of supports them ... but you're not using it.

Comment: And why the interface works in getAllGoods()??

Comment: you aren't using the Interface in your case, you have hacked the entity name to be the name of the interface class. This is what JPQL uses, and interprets it as GoodsImp. So the title of the question is nonsense

Comment: I hacked how the table will be called i think.But then i use the Goods.class to convert the object to that specific class. I think that the part that I "hacked" is to call in the select Goods instead of GoodsImp, but why I can use Goods.class here. If JPA gets for JPQL the "hacked" why is not getting for .find method? I appreciate your help, but i want to understand the difference between the two methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `EntityManager` method `createQuery` you used is declared as:

```
<T> TypedQuery<T> createQuery(String qlString, Class<T> resultClass)
```

The **only** reason for the `Class<T> resultClass` parameter is to infer the type of `T`, so that you could write:

```
List<Goods> listOfGoods = em.createQuery("select g from Goods g where id=:id", Goods.class).getResultList();
```

without getting compiler warnings. The `resultClass` parameter is **certainly not** telling the `entityManager` which entity type you are querying for. This is done by the `select g from Goods g` part of the query, and incidentally, `Goods` is an alias for the entity `GoodsImpl` (you could annotate the `GoodsImpl` entity with `@Entity(name = "Bads")` and `select b from Bads b` would also work).

Now, if I understand correctly, you're asking why the call `em.find(entityClass, primaryKey)` fails when `Goods.class` is used for `entityClass`. You can find the answer in the javadoc for `EntityManager`, in which `find` is said to throw:

> IllegalArgumentException - if the first argument does not denote an entity type

An entity type is, unsurprisingly, a class annotated with `@Entity`.

If you're asking *why* this is the way it is implemented, then the answer is pretty simple. An interface can be implemented by several classes. Suppose you had multiple entity classes implementing `Goods`, each with its own table and its own id. There would be no reason for ids not overlap across these different entities. How is JPA supposed to know which of these entities you're hoping to get?

Comment: Great answer, this is what i want. Thanks a lot. So my options are, use the TypedQuery with alias or the find method using the entity itself. Thanks a lot.